# Bash: remove file suffix in one command line

Tags: bash, command-line, find

Given file path such as `fiz.js` and `dir/buz.js`, how to remove suffixes to obtain `fiz dir/buz`?

My best shot (I'm looking for something simpler):

```
find -name '*.js'| \
 xargs -I{} echo {} | \
 sed 's/.js$//' | \
 xargs -I{} mv {}.js {}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do it with just `bash` (version 4) by using `globstar` to get a recursive file list.

```
$ shopt -s globstar
$ for i in **/*.js ; do echo "$i" "${i%.js}" ; done
```

For the bash man page:

> #### `globstar`
>
> If set, the pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all  files  and zero  or more directories and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only                       directories and subdirectories match.

`${x%ext}` removes `ext` from the end of `$x`. See [String manipulations](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "fiz.js"|awk -F. '{print $1}'

echo "dir/buz.js"|awk -F. '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find -name '*.js'|  xargs -I file rename 's/\.js$//' file
```

it works and if you want to overwrite existing files you have to add a -f to rename (rename  -f).

Comment: Please use answers only to provide answers, not to ask your own questions

Answer (score 0):

This works for me  : `rename ".js" "" *.js`